# Is there a way to display db2 data in grafana

Tags: python, sql, db2, grafana

We use db2 at our company. I would like to find a way to query db2 for data and display that data in grafana. For example to get a number of completed transactions.

I see grafana does support mysql natively but not db2. Is there a way to just add the db2 driver/libraries?

Worst case is writing queries in python and then simply displaying that recorded data with grafana an effective solution?

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow may be the wrong forum for your question. Try https://community.grafana.com/search?q=db2

Comment: The reason why I am asking here is because I suspect there will also be a middleware needed, which will fall outside of the scope of "only" grafana. But let me try there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you found what you need but in case you didn´t you might consider using 'Db2 rest services' and Grafana plugin 'Simple JSON Datasource'.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, two suitable datasources have been developed

- [grafana-odbc-datasource](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-odbc-datasource/)
- [grafana-db2-datasource](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-db2-datasource/)

Unfortunately, both **require an enterprise license**.

We're currently evaluating other approaches like copying the data in a PostgreSQL database with an ETL-like job.

A generic ODBC/JDBC plugin is really needed.